# Idea Gradle integration add classes as a test source tree, but don't include in test sourceSet

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, source-sets

I would like to mark the classes of my systest sourceSet as unit test classes. I tried to mark them with the following code:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    groovy {
      srcDirs = [
              'src/main/masks'
    }

    resources {
      srcDirs += 'src/main/journaltemplates'
    }
  }

  /* This brings up systest in the test resources */
  test.java.srcDir 'src/systest/java'
  test.resources.srcDir 'src/systest/resources'

  systest {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/systest/java']
    }

    resources {
      srcDirs = ['src/systest/resources']
    }
  }
}
```

With this solution the sourceset got marked as unit test class, but was additionally added to the test sourceSet which is not desired. I want to keep the classes in the systest sourceSet and specify that the systest sourceSet, is a unit test sourceSet. I want the same behaviour for the systest sourceSet as for the test sourceSet, but they should be distinct sourceSets.

---

The second solution i tried was using the idea plugin for gradle and modify the module setting, as seen [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369060/gradle-custom-test-sourceset):

```
idea {
  module {
    testSourceDirs += file('src/systest')
  }
}
```

The problem with this solution is that the systest sources are added to the test sourceSet too.

Hopefully this is clear enough, otherwise please comment. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated Gradle feature called `Declarative Test Suite` that supports this case:

```
testing {
    suites {
        val test by getting(JvmTestSuite::class) {
            useJUnitJupiter()
        }

        register("integrationTest", JvmTestSuite::class) {
            dependencies {
                implementation(project())
            }

            targets {
                all {
                    testTask.configure {
                        shouldRunAfter(test)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

More:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests

Answer (score 0):

Please try this configuration:

```
apply plugin: "idea"
sourceSets {
    systest {

        java {
            compileClasspath = test.output + main.output
            runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath 
        }
    }

}

idea {
    module {
        testSourceDirs = sourceSets.systest.allSource.srcDirs
    }
}
```

Comment: But isn't srcDirs = ['src/systest/java'] missing then?

Comment: And it doesn't seem to work. Is not marked as test source :-/